# Is there a way to map a Java Servlet to */?

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I want to map a `Servlet` to URLs ending in `/`, like `/user/register/`, `/user/login/`, but not any other resource under that path, not `/*`.

I tried `/*/`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I'm not sure this is possible.  the wildcard * is only used at the end of url patterns:

```
# this is a valid pattern to match anything after root:
*/
# this does not match anything because nothing can come after *
/*/
# this would match anything after the . that was htm
*.htm
```

Comment: `*/` is an invalid url-pattern as well.

Comment: /*/ matches exactly /*/. i check the source code of tomcat, but i don't think there is anyway:<

Answer (score 1):

Map a `Filter` on `/*` and let it determine whether the request needs to be passed through the servlet or not.

```
if (request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/")) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/servleturl").forward(request, response);
} else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

This way you can just map the desired `Servlet` on `/servleturl`.

Answer (score 0):

welcome-file-list is what you are looking for.
under the welcome-file-list you can specify a list of welcome-files (each under its own welcome-file tag). When the request URL ends with /, the application would look for the presence of one of those files you have mentioned in welcome-file-list (in the order you have specified there i guess) under the folder pointed to by the URL, and serve that resource.